# Laravel 4 tables relationship Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have four tables:

Users: id, username
Roles: id, name
Domains id, title
DomainsAssignedRolesUsers id, role_id, user_id, domain_id

I want to get all user roles for a domain.

I do:

```
User::find(1)->domains->first()->roles
```

But i get all domains roles, not only for my user. Help me to get user roles only for the selected domain/

My relations:

```
// User model:

public function rolesDomain() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'domainsAssignedRolesUsers', 'user_id', 'role_id');
}

public function domains() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Domain', 'domainsAssignedRolesUsers');
}
```

---

```
// Role model:

public function domains() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Domain', 'domainsAssignedRolesUsers');
}
```

---

```
// Domain model:

public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'domainsAssignedRolesUsers', 'domain_id', 'role_id');
}

public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'domainsAssignedRolesUsers', 'domain_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get all the roles, from a specific domain, in relation with an user?

So this should do the trick:

```
User::find(1)->rolesDomain()->where('domain_id', $specificID)->get()
```

But if you want to only get the roles from the first domain for an user.

```
User::find(1)->domains()->first()->roles()->get();
```

And if you only want to retrieve the roles for a user.

```
User::find(1)->rolesDomain()->get()
```

And if you only want to retrieve all the roles from each domain in relation with an user.

```
User::find(1)->domains()->with('roles')->get()
```

Even if Eloquent documentation has a few example, This orm is really intuitive.

Comment: Here I get all domains. Not just for my user

Comment: It does'nt work :( Here I get all roles by domain. Not only by my user.

Comment: Maybe you should change your domains method in user model into

return $this->belongsToMany('Domain', 'domain_assigned_roles', 'user_id', 'domain_id');

I can assure the case for me works, I have a blogpost which have many categories which have many tags, if I do Post::find(1)->categories()->first()->tags()->get() I get All the tags from the first category in relation with the first post

Comment: Ok so I think I get where I was wrong.
Maybe this will work for your case: User::find(1)->rolesDomain()->get()
I didn't realized that you wanted to get only the roles for an user.
If its that you just have to use the direct relation between a user and his roles

Comment: I want to get my user roles for exactly domain. Not all roles for user :)

Comment: Ok so I edited.
Check the last proposition.
If you have the ID domain you could do this

Comment: Yeaaah!
Thank you! It works!
And one more question.
How can i get roles for each domain by user?

Comment: You're Welcome !
My first proposition should do the job.
User::find(1)->domains()->with('roles')->get()

If you mean that you want to get all the roles from each domain in relation with a user.

Comment: User::find(1)->domains()->with('roles')->get() when i do this, i get all roles for a domain, not only for my user. Why?:(

Comment: Sorry I wasn't available these days.
So try User::find(1)->rolesDomain()->get()

Comment: I want to get all user domains with his role :)

Comment: Ok so I don't know.
Manually you could do it.
it depends on how you organize your data in your object.
For example you should first retrieve your user with his domains.
Then you just have to retrieve foreach domains, all the roles in relation with the domain in question and the user.
What I mean is that you have to separate your queries for the userDomain part and the userRolesDomain part.
I don't know the Eloquent method to do it sorry.
Must be SuperSimple.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Eloquent Triple Pivot](https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/Eloquent-triple-pivot) (also on Packagist), it sounds like it does exactly what you want.

You'd set up your Models as `User`, `Domain` and `Role` (a `User` has many `Domain`s and can have a `Role` in each). Then look at the docs on the Github page (particularly step 6), and you'd define this on your `Domain` model:

```
class Domain extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function getRolesAttribute() {
        return $this->getThirdAttribute();
    }
}
```

Then you can simply call

```
$user = User::find(1);

$domain = $user->domains->first();
// or
$domain = $user->domains->find(73);

$roles = $domain->roles;

// Or the above can be condensed into just...
$roles = User::findOrFail( 1 )
             ->domains()
             ->findOrFail( 73 )
             ->roles;
```

Comment: Just a little fix: `->domains()->findOrFail`, `->domains()->first(..)` - with `()`, otherwise you work on the collection. That said `first` will work, but `findOrFail` will throw error, since it's Eloquent Builder's method.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Good catch :-) I'll go amend my other answer that I copy/pasted from as well :P

Comment: I do all, but now i have an Exception:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::getThirdKey()

Here: TriplePivotTrait.php on line 62

Comment: @LastRide check the GitHub docs - I think you've missed out step 4 in one or more models

Comment: And how can I make this without this package?

Comment: @LastRide implement all the functionality the package provides, but with your own code? I don't really understand the question